# Does salting water make it less diamagnetic?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, water, physical-chemistry, ions

I read some where that adding salt to water makes it less diamagnetic, but I've checked and  water, sodium and chlorine ions are all diamagnetic. If salt water really is less diamagnetic, how is it so?

Answer (score 3):

Magnetic molar susceptibility of salt NaCl (χ)= −30.2·10E−6 cm3/mol [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chloride)

Magnetic molar susceptibility of water (χ)= −1.298×10E−5 cm3/mol [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chloride)

The ionic bond of salt NaCl breaks down when salt is disolved in water, described in this process here:

https://www.usgs.gov/media/images/water-molecules-and-their-interaction-salt

Discrete Na and Cl molecules bond with water molecules.

Magnetic molar susceptibility of Cl (χ)= −40.5×10E−6 cm3/mol [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine)

Magnetic molar susceptibility of **sodium** Na (χ)= **+16.0×10E−6 cm3/mol (at room temeperature)** [[3]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium)

This last one positive value of sodium Na indicates that it is paramagnetic.

**Therefore the water molecules which are bonded with sodium Na will become less diamagnetic as a net effect.**

**Final answer: Salted water is less diamagnetic.**

Comment: Should we not look at the Magnetic Molar Susceptibility of the ions? And not the actual metal?

Comment: @Tardigradesarecool  Since the Na+ and Cl- ions bond separately with the electric dipole H2O water molecules I don't believe you can call these ions anymore but rather "metallic water" :) The WP gives the magnetic values for the atoms of Na and Cl and not their ions. The Na which has one unpaired electron at its outer shell glued with the water molecules will be still paramagnetic and attracted to an external strong magnetic field.